# Listen to api server with nativescript

Tags: http, fetch, nativescript

i have a task to listen to an api server all the time for a project naativescript+angular. The api call will return true/false output, on each time i hit the api via browser or postman, i need to reflect that in my app (by default we can set as false, only need to console.log true statement when i initiate that action). Ignore the case with device id or identification of the device. Tried with socket.io but no luck, anything we can go with http module or fetch will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to try https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-background-http

Answer (score 0):

It's not advisable to hit server again and again, so sockets are your best option. There are several plugins implementing sockets in NativeScript, especially you may give a try for [socket.io](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-socketio) / [websockets](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-websockets). If you face any issues, try their demo app with their demo server to ensure it's not a issue from plugin.

Or you may even consider using FCM for sending a data message to device if you that works for you, of course that needs device id.